# OnTouch Event To Show Precise X,Y Values

Tags: android-graphview

Is it possible to display a label using the X and Y values for each critical point? Like this. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android GraphView library can not do this out of the box, but there is a patch on github that should do this:
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/pull/9

so you have to patch it on your own....